# How to hide <h3> in div tags with css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to hide this div's h3 tag without adding a class. I have tried in various ways with the css but I have not succeeded. Can anyone recommend me an alternative?

Since the html code is in a plugin file I cannot act on it directly.

```
<div class="wpua-edit-container">
<h3>Profile Picture</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: _"I have tried in various ways"_ - please update the question with [mcve]s showing these.

Comment: Doesn't this work? `div.wpua-edit-container > h3 { display: none; }`

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```css
div h3 {display:none}
```

```html
<div class="wpua-edit-container">
<h3>Profile Picture</h3>
<p>hello...</p>
</div>
```

Also, you may do:

1. div h3 {display:none;}
2. div.wpua-edit-container h3 {display:none;}
3. .wpua-edit-container h3 {display:none;}
4. .wpua-edit-container > h3 {display:none;}
5. div.wpua-edit-container > h3 {display:none;}

All, of these should work. Additionally, add !important if required, if your plugin is still not removing it, like `{display: none!important}`.

Answer (score -2):

You can use jQuery if you want:

here's the index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wpua-edit-container">
            <h3>Profile Picture</h3>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("h3").hide()
})
```

It's basically doing the same thing as `display: none;` (it adds to the element the display: none style property to the element) but using jQuery.

Comment: I downvoted this answer because: 1) No-one should be using jQuery today. and 2) Adding a hard dependency on an externally hosted script _cannot end well_ (XSS attacks, etc), 3) This won't work with users where JS is disabled or if the CDN goes down. 4) This answer epitomizes the worst parts of the JavaScript developer ecosystem today. 5) The script hides _all_ `<h3>` elements regardless of context or location in the DOM. 6) The use of `$(document).ready(...)` means that the `<h3>` elements will be fully visible to users until the browser fully loads the HTML structure, which is jarring.

Comment: you are totally right, i don't know if I should delete my answer or keep it so there's your comment.